# Autofit and minHeight in Excel Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I created a small macro in Excel, which inserts a new sheet with certain names and makes some adjustments (formatting, background colors, column widths etc.). 
This also works wonderfully.

My problem is that I want to give certain rows the property "Autofit" and a minimum height. The last has optical reasons. Autofit because it can be that the content becomes multiline.

Unfortunately, I can't get the combination of the two. Either I have a height or the Autofit.

Here is my existing code:

```
    Sheets(sn).Range("B4:H50").WrapText = True
    Sheets(sn).Range("B4:H50").Rows.AutoFit
   'Sheets(sn).Range("B4:H50").RowHeight = 30

    Dim Rng As Range
    Sheets(sn).Range("A4:H50").Select
    For Each Rng In Selection.Cells
        Rng.RowHeight = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng.RowHeight, 50)
    Next Rng
```

The attempt with the MinRowHeight I had found at Google. It sets the height correct, but then the autofit is deactivated again.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to consider couple of facts:

1. If you want to "give certain rows the property "Autofit" and a minimum height." Then you should you use auto fit first, then in your `for each` loop use the `Max` function instead of `Min`. Like this:

```
Sub sheetFormat()

    Dim sn As Integer, formatRng As Range, minHeight

    sn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count 'To format the last worksheet in this workbook
    Set formatRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sn).Range("B4:H50")
    minHeight = 30 'or 50

    formatRng.WrapText = True
    formatRng.Rows.AutoFit

    Dim Rng As Range
    For Each Rng In formatRng
        Rng.RowHeight = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng.RowHeight, minHeight)
    Next Rng

End Sub
```

That code will do what you asked for, but only if you are formatting the sheet after you fill the cells with contents. This code will NOT `AutoFit` the row height if -after calling this SUB- you fill a cell within the `formatRng` with characters that don't fit in a `minHeight` point row-height. It will only format the cells that already have contents according to this rule:
(All cells in the range `formatRng` have a minimum row height of `minHeight`, and the cells that have content not fitting in this `minHeight` have larger row-height decided by `AutoFit`).

2. When you specify the row height **explicitly** with `Range.RowHeight` to 30 for example, you are telling excel to not adjust the height achieving best fit (i.e, you're disabling `.AutoFit` feature), and it won't adjust the height larger automatically. There are just no ways of doing this.

That means you need to leave the row height set to **implicitly** adjust (done by choosing AutoFit as the row height) and, somehow, get it to go no lower than `minheight` if you want to solve the problem in 1. and avoid explicit adjustment of row-height.

This can be done by making the font size of a cell in each row in our `formatRng` larger, so the height would get larger in these rows to reach `minheight`, and then when we use `autofit` in these rows, it will make the 'default row height' -even of blank cells- no lower than `minheight`.

By trial and error I found that 40 pt Arial font makes row-height 50, here's a vba code to achieve that:

```
Sub sheetFormat()

    Dim sn As Integer, formatRng As Range
    sn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count 'To format the last worksheet in this workbook
    Set formatRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sn).Range("B4:H50")

    Dim p As Integer, q As Integer, lastColStr As String
    p = formatRng.Row      'first row of the range
    q = formatRng.Rows.Count + p - 1   'last row of the range
    lastColStr = Mid(Cells(1, Columns.Count).Address, 2, 3)  'Last column Name (XFD on my machine)

'    Making Cells in the range "XFD4:XFD50" have 40pt Arial font
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sn).Range(lastColStr & p & ":" & lastColStr & q)
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 40
    End With

    formatRng.WrapText = True
    formatRng.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter  'I added this one just to see the whole contents of the cell
    formatRng.Rows.AutoFit

End Sub
```

For details about this trick:

https://excelribbon.tips.net/T005663_Changing_Default_Row_Height.html

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. This didn't solve my problem at all, because it's more like a template and the content gets add afterward. But I know that there is no way to do that. Thanks again.

Comment: Even if it's a template and contents get added afterwards, The second code block of my answer did achieve what you were asking for on my machine. Can you tell me what didn't work out for you?

Comment: I missunderstood the part with the font size. I've been over the article and there was descripted to set the default font size, which is not an options. A second look (after a coffee) to your code makes perfectly sense :)